# Facing problem in doing Sigle Sign On on Windows using Qt

Tags: c++, windows, azure, qt, single-sign-on

We are doing sign-on or SSO log-in in the Qt application. We are using Qt version 5.12.4 for a desktop application and using QtWebEngine to load the Microsoft authentication page.

When a request like the following goes

https://login.microsoftonline.com/54b90cf0-8817-42de-893f-9d32076b4a9b/saml2?SAMLRequest=jZFPa8MwDMW%2FSvB9cf64xDNJwG1aKHQw2nWH3Uym0UBip5ZS9vGXpORUGAWdhJ70fk85mq7tlR7oYo9wHQAp%2BO1aiwUbvFXOYIPKmg5QUa1O%2Bu2gkjBSHZD5NmRYsK8KtpOiklJqna6F2MRrKUSarbTYyiSOqtctCz7BY%2BNswUbxqEEcYG%2BRjKWxFSXpSzSW%2BIhjFaUqlmG2yr6muXeD2NygYD%2BmRWCBRgRP46aNszh04E%2Fgb00N5%2BOhYBeiHhXnvfNk2qsJR%2FMEYe06juj4RMongocl7I6s5iz%2BB%2B%2B9I1e7lgU752uYc1vclfkM5p8J0CweWPmM7SXvnN9PlDl%2FfFz5Bw%3D%3D

we are getting following response instead of SAMLResponse token.

```html
<!-- This jsp is designed due to caching issue in Chrome. because after login when call was redirected to home servlet at that time 
    it was making call of cached data images/js/css to revalidate it (304 status code) --><html><head>
    <title>CompnayName</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        localStorage.setItem("isFromLogin", "true");
        function redirectToAdoddleHome(){
            document.frmHome.action_id.value=1;
            document.frmHome.submit();
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="redirectToAdoddleHome();">
    
    <form name="frmHome" id="frmHome" action="/adoddle/home" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" id="action_id" name="action_id" value="1">
    </form> 
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
Qt Code that we are using:

QString AsiteSSOManager::CallLoginToRP(const QString& strSSOADFSURL, const QString& strSSOTargetURL)
    {

    QString retValHTML = "";
    m_view = new QWebEngineView();
    m_view->showFullScreen();
    m_view->page()->profile()->cookieStore()->deleteAllCookies();
    m_view->page()->profile()->setPersistentCookiesPolicy(QWebEngineProfile::NoPersistentCookies);
    m_view->page()->profile()->setHttpCacheType(QWebEngineProfile::NoCache);
    QString strURL = "";
    if (strSSOADFSURL.contains("?"))
    {
        strURL = QString("%1%2%3").arg(strSSOADFSURL).arg("&loginToRp=").arg(strSSOTargetURL);
    }
    else
    {
        strURL = QString("%1%2%3").arg(strSSOADFSURL).arg(LOGIN_TO_RP).arg(strSSOTargetURL);
    }
    
    connect(m_view, &QWebEngineView::loadFinished, this, &AsiteSSOManager::OnLoginToRPLoadFinished);
    connect(m_view->page(), &QWebEnginePage::authenticationRequired, this, &AsiteSSOManager::HandleAuthenticationRequired);
    m_view->load(strURL);

    if (strSSOADFSURL.contains("?"))
    {
        m_view->show();
    }

    m_timer.start();
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(this, &AsiteSSOManager::RequiredHTMLReceived, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    loop.exec();

    retValHTML = m_loginToRPResponse;
    m_view->stop();
    m_view->page()->profile()->cookieStore()->deleteAllCookies();
    m_timer.stop();
    if (m_view)
    {
        m_view->deleteLater();
    }
    return retValHTML;
}

void AsiteSSOManager::OnTimeOut()
{
    //emit RequiredHTMLReceived();
}

void AsiteSSOManager::OnLoginToRPLoadFinished(bool ok)
{
    if (ok)
    {
        m_view->page()->toHtml(
            [&](const QString &html)
        {
            if (html.contains("SAMLResponse") || html.contains("aSessionId"))
            {
                m_loginToRPResponse = html; 
                emit RequiredHTMLReceived();
                //qDebug() << m_loginToRPResponse;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any clue why are we not getting SAMLResponse.
Also, please note that this code works intermittently. Sometimes we do get the SAML response. But, it is not the case that every time the code works.

Comment: Could you please share the Qt sample link that you are trying.

Comment: Added Qt code that we use.

Comment: I found that the problem is because of caching is not getting cleared. If I remove cache manually it works.
Though calling following

 m_view->page()->profile()->setPersistentCookiesPolicy(QWebEngineProfile::NoPersistentCookies);
 m_view->page()->profile()->setHttpCacheType(QWebEngineProfile::NoCache);
 m_view->page()->profile()->clearAllVisitedLinks();
 m_view->page()->profile()->clearHttpCache();
does not clear the web engine's cache. How can we clear the cache of QWebEngineView?